# Trying to import the bootstrap library in my rails 5.x application for my custom layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I created a new layout for my marketing site and I want to import the bootstrap library for that layout only.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clhweb</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'marketing', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>marketing</p>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a marketing.scss file in my assets/stylesheets folder:

```
@import "vendor/bootstrap/boostrap";
```

I downloaded the bootstrap scss files and put them all in the vendor/bootstrap folder.

And I got the error saying I have to add it to the precompile list, so I did that:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( marketing.scss )
```

Now when I load the page it says:

> File to import not found or unreadable: vendor/bootstrap/boostrap.

Why can't it locate the bootstrap scss file?

The /assets/stylesheets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss file has:

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "root";
@import "reboot";
@import "type";
@import "images";
@import "code";
@import "grid";
@import "tables";
@import "forms";
@import "buttons";
@import "transitions";
@import "dropdown";
@import "button-group";
@import "input-group";
@import "custom-forms";
@import "nav";
@import "navbar";
@import "card";
@import "breadcrumb";
@import "pagination";
@import "badge";
@import "jumbotron";
@import "alert";
@import "progress";
@import "media";
@import "list-group";
@import "close";
@import "modal";
@import "tooltip";
@import "popover";
@import "carousel";
@import "utilities";
@import "print";
```

Comment: Is it `marketing.css` or `marketing.scss`?

Comment: it is marketing.scss, I tried both in the assets initializer and same error.  I'll change it to scss as it makes more sense.

Comment: Is it in `app/assets` folder or in `vendor/assets` folder?

Comment: @Pavan the boostrap files are in ```app/assets/stylesheets/vendor/bootstrap folder ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> File to import not found or unreadable: vendor/bootstrap/boostrap.

You have a typo in your code

```
@import "vendor/bootstrap/boostrap"; #missing 't' in bootstrap
```

should be

```
@import "vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap";
```